# Non-Clustered Index - Including 2 Columns Always Null - Improved Search?

Tags: sql-server, search, indexing, null, non-clustered-index

I have been asked to review a series of indexes before they get added to our 2019 SQL db. I am not an index person and do not normally do this so I am trying to understand why I should add the one below.

The code below is adding two columns to a non-clustered index, when those two columns are always null. Essentially, I have a Part Master table that has 3 "sub category" fields. We only use 1 of those subcategory fields and never plan on using the others, so part_subgrp1 is populated while part_subgrp2 & 3 are always null. My peer keeps saying it will improve performance but they cannot explain why and I can't seem to get past how two blank fields help optimize search (at least in a meaningful way).

Here is the code:

```
5. new index from table partmstr
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_partmstr_sellable_inclPartSubgrp2] ON [dbo].[partmstr]
(
    [sellable], [part_grp]
)
include ([part_subgrp2],[part_subgrp3]  )
GO
```

I don't know that it matters for the question but the table has 343 columns and 7704 records (and confirmed those two part sub groups are null for every one of those).

If he is correct I just want a better understanding of why so I don't feel like I am just putting junk in.

Thank you!

I am new, so if I jacked this up I will totally correct it. Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the query: if the query uses those columns then yes it may improve performance. What query are you trying to improve, and what is it's current query plan (share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan)? But such an index on a 343 column table is probably lipstick on a very large pig

Comment: _My peer keeps saying it will improve performance_ You do not add indexes to a production database as an "experiment". That statement sounds like your peer has no evidence and the suggestion is based on "feeling". Is that accurate? Does peer **know** that this change will improve anything? And if your org never plans to populate those columns, there should be constraints in place to guarantee that never happens.